# SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have downloaded TensorFlow but when trying to check if it is well installed and running code to check it appears SyntaxError: Multiple statements...
How can I solve this?

This is for a new Windows 10 computer which I have installed in the same process Tensorwflow, Anaconda, cuDNN and Cuda toolkit.

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >
> > > hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
> > >
> > > sess = tf.Session()
> > >
> > > print(sess.run(hello))
> > >
> > > SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

It appears in red the first statement and the last one.

Comment: are you having it as a py file or running these in command line as statements ?

Comment: Running the command line as statements

Comment: thats the reason. execute statements one by one. or save it in a .py file and run it.

Comment: It doesn't work. I saved the file in a .py and says the same.

Comment: When trying to import TensorFlow it says DLL load failed.